# Troubleshooting consistent "SQLException: Lock wait timeout exceeded"

Tags: mysql, jdbc, transactions, locking, quartz-scheduler

I have an application running Quartz 1.6.1 w/persistent job store, with MySQL 5.1 as the DB. This application used to boot up okay in Tomcat6. At some point, it began throwing the following exception upon EVERY boot:

```
- MisfireHandler: Error handling misfires: Failure obtaining db row lock: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.LockException: Failure obtaining db row lock: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction [See nested exception: java.sql.SQLException: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction]
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdRowLockSemaphore.executeSQL(StdRowLockSemaphore.java:112)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.DBSemaphore.obtainLock(DBSemaphore.java:112)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.doRecoverMisfires(JobStoreSupport.java:3075)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$MisfireHandler.manage(JobStoreSupport.java:3838)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$MisfireHandler.run(JobStoreSupport.java:3858)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1055)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3491)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1936)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2060)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2542)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1734)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1885)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:76)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdRowLockSemaphore.executeSQL(StdRowLockSemaphore.java:92)
    ... 4 more
```

I should mention this application also utilizes JPA w/Hibernate using C3P0 for data source connection pooling. This exception is always thrown directly after JPA finishes updating my schema.

First, I upgraded to Quartz 1.6.5 and the exception went away, but the application appears frozen. The last thing in the logs - where the exception used to be - is:

```
...hbm2ddl stuff...
2969 [Thread-1] INFO org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate - schema update complete
- Handling 6 trigger(s) that missed their scheduled fire-time.
```

With nothing coming after, and the webapp not servicing requests; they just hang indefinitely.

When I run **mysql** command-line client with *SHOW INNODB STATUS* right after the exception, it does consistently show two suspicious transactions:

```
----------
SEMAPHORES
----------
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: reservation count 49, signal count 49
Mutex spin waits 0, rounds 2100, OS waits 0
RW-shared spins 115, OS waits 49; RW-excl spins 0, OS waits 0
------------
TRANSACTIONS
------------
Trx id counter 0 165688
Purge done for trx's n:o < 0 165685 undo n:o < 0 0
History list length 12
LIST OF TRANSACTIONS FOR EACH SESSION:
---TRANSACTION 0 0, not started, OS thread id 5012
MySQL thread id 8, query id 1798 localhost 127.0.0.1 root
SHOW INNODB STATUS
---TRANSACTION 0 165687, ACTIVE 300 sec, OS thread id 3772
2 lock struct(s), heap size 320, 1 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 30, query id 1795 localhost 127.0.0.1 my_app
---TRANSACTION 0 165685, ACTIVE 360 sec, OS thread id 5460
2 lock struct(s), heap size 320, 1 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 34, query id 1680 localhost 127.0.0.1 my_app
```

I'm looking for guidance on how to further investigate this issue. Perhaps if I could somehow identify the owners of these two transactions, or what resources they are locking?

**Update:** I deleted all rows in the *qrtz_simple_triggers* table without problem. I then tried to do the same on the *qrtz_triggers* table and my MySQL client threw a "Lock wait timeout exceeded" error. At this point I stopped my (still hanging) application and was then able to delete all rows of the *qrtz_triggers* table. Once this was done I was able to successfully boot my application.

It appears I need to log a new Quartz bug, but I'd like to be able to give them more information about what is actually hapenning here. So, as per the original question, how can I troubleshoot these types of issues?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running
 
`show processlist` 
or 
`show full processlist` 
from the mysql command line?
These will normally show you the full sql for the query that is locking. It will also show you how long the process has been running that query. It may help you get closer to the answer.